# Is there a control from Microsoft to display Power BI reports in my asp.net application the same way as using the WebReportViewer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, powerbi

Is there a control from Microsoft to display Power BI reports in my asp.net application the same way as using the WebReportViewer?

Does Microsoft provide a control to display an already developed Power BI report in my application. All I have is the URL of the report and I just want to display it in my app.

Comment: you can try this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/integrate-report

Comment: If you're using PowerBI Report Server you can simply use use an iframe - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/quickstart-embed

Comment: @ADyson does embedding the report this way will require the user to enter Credentials? I want to display the report directly without asking for credentials

Comment: If it uses Windows Authentication there's no particular reason why it should. It depends how your report is secured.